# SCSS foreach to make calc spacing rules

Tags: css, sass

I have found an awesome way to give responsive spacing!!! Problem is, I would like to make my CSS maintainable, rather than hardcoding lots of properties.

At the moment, I just hardcode:

```
.u-marg-t-xxl {
  margin-top: calc(200px + 140 * (100vw - 320px) / 1120); }

.u-marg-t-xl {
  margin-top: calc(120px + 99 * (100vw - 320px) / 1120); }

.u-marg-t-lg {
  margin-top: calc(71px + 24 * (100vw - 320px) / 1120); }

.u-marg-t-md {
  margin-top: calc(32px + 12 * (100vw - 320px) / 1120); }

.u-marg-t-sm {
  margin-top: calc(15px + 12 * (100vw - 320px) / 1120); }

.u-marg-t-xs {
  margin-top: calc(4px + 12 * (100vw - 320px) / 1120); }
```

The problem is, I would need to do this for `b`: bottom, `y`: top and bottom, `x`: left and right. At present, my CSS is just not maintainable.

How could I use the loop below, but just print different integers in the first arguments (X)?

`margin-top:calc( Xpx + X * (100vw - 320px) / 1120);`

I do have this, but I can't get my head around the `calc` part.

```
$sizes: xs, sm, md, lg, xl, xxl;
$incre: 22;

@for $i from 1 through 6 {
    .u-marg-t- {
        &#{nth($sizes, $i)} {
            margin-top: calc( 0px + ($i * $incre) * (100vw - 320) / 1120 );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a complex sass map?

```
$sizes: (
  xs: (
    size: 4px,
    inc: 22,
  ),
  sm: (
    size: 15px,
    inc: 44,
  ),
  md: (
    size: 32px,
    inc: 66,
  ),
  lg: (
    size: 71px,
    inc: 88,
  ),
  xl: (
    size: 120px,
    inc: 110,
  ),
  xxl: (
    size: 200px,
    inc: 132,
  )
);

@each $key, $map in $sizes {
  .u-marg-t-#{$key} {
    margin-top: calc( #{map-get($map, size)} + #{map-get($map, inc)} * (100vw - 320) / 1120 );
  }
}
```

Since you want this to work for `margin-top`, `margin-left`, etc. you could even set it up as a mixin, and call the mixin through a list.

```
@mixin responsive-sizing($var) {
  @each $key, $map in $sizes {
    .u-marg-#{$var}-#{$key} {
      margin-#{$var}: calc( #{map-get($map, size)} + #{map-get($map, inc)} * (100vw - 320) / 1120 );
    }
  }
}

$responsive-vars: 'top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right';

@each $var in $responsive-vars {
  @include responsive_sizing($var);
}
```

This should compile to include classes like:

```
.u-marg-top-xs {
  margin-top: calc( 4px + 22 * (100vw - 320) / 1120);
}
```

and

```
.u-marg-bottom-md {
  margin-bottom: calc( 32px + 66 * (100vw - 320) / 1120);
}
```

[Here's a good additional resource for complex maps and lists](https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-maps-vs-nested-lists/)